# How do I recompile an Ionic 1.x app?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, build

I built an Ionic app a couple years ago with Ionix 1.x and JavaScript. It's been running fine for quite a while, but now it needs to be recompiled to allow for use on iOS 11. My build is now completely broken with the ionic@latest updates.

My question is how do I get the correct version of Ionic installed on my dev machine so that this app can compile? Should I be able to use the latest ionic-cli command with an older version of the Ionic dependencies? I'm not ready to port my application to Ionic 2+ and Angular 2+ and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

ionic@latest cli is fine for building an ionic1 project but you will find some compatibility issues with older platforms and plugins. Suggest you start by updating the platform:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

For some of the latest iOS 11 issues and in particular, iPhone X screen issues, you may want to try:

```
cordova platform update ios@4.5.0
```

For any plugins that are causing problems, you will need to remove them individually and re-add them:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-xxxx --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-xxxx --save
```